# Does season matter when seeds are grown?

Tags: seeds, germination

I'd like to start growing houseplants from seed in the UK. Given that it's almost November, does this make any difference when it comes to growing indoors? It won't be quite as warm, but it will obviously still be a comfortable human temperature in my flat. Or do I need to wait until next spring?

Comment: Which plants? Generally though, the reason for not starting seeds this time of year is not warmth or lack of it, though that does matter, but steadily increasing lack of day light - by December, there will only be 7 hours of daylight available.

Answer (score 4):

It depends.

Some plants have a natural annual cycle, but your plants may not be native to your part of the world so that may be either irrelevant or out of sync with your seasons.

Some seeds need a cool "over winter" period (or artificial "stratification" in a fridge) before they will germinate.

Some seeds need to be sown on the surface of the compost and may need the correct day length or light level to germinate.

After they germinate, seedlings may need a relatively high light level to develop properly. (Low light levels causing etiolated seedlings are a common cause of failure.)

You need advice that is specific to the species you want to grow.

Comment: So indoors if I'm using artificial light to simulate day length (and normal room temperature) and the seeds have been through the preparation process I can grow pretty much anything from seed?